# Test SQL Parameter for null or blank value

Tags: c#, sql

I'm performing a simple insert into an SQL database. The query is parametrised but when I call the method which performs this insert I may not always want to populate each parameter.

As follows:

```
using (var sqlconnection = new SqlConnection(Globals.AFWideSettings.SqlConnectionString))
            {
                sqlconnection.Open();
                using (
                    var sqlcommand =
                        new SqlCommand(
                            "insert into DataActions (afuser, aftable, changetype, originaldata, newdata) values (@afuser, @aftable, @changetype, @originaldata, @newdata);",
                            sqlconnection))
                {

                    sqlcommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("afuser", userActions.AfUser));
                    sqlcommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("aftable", userActions.AfTable));
                    sqlcommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("changetype", userActions.ChangeType));
                    sqlcommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("originaldata", userActions.OriginalData));
                    sqlcommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("newdata", userActions.NewData));

                    sqlcommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
                sqlconnection.Close();
            }
        }
```

If I was testing for Null information coming out of the database I would do something like:

```
Id = getRecords.IsDBNull(0) ? -1 : getRecords.GetInt32(0)
```

Is there a equivalent way of doing this on sqlparameters ? I'm stumped.

(I know I could test each item individually, I just want to be efficient)

Many thanks

Comment: You could create a stored procedure that has NULL as default values, then you pass in only the data you have. Have you written SPs before?

Comment: not many, I tend to do everything in VS (still learning)

Comment: What flavour of SQL are you using? Oracle, SQL Server, IBM etc.

Comment: Damo btw you are not stupid actually you asking a question is a good thing and this is a good question in my opinion personally I would recommend changing the sqlcommand.Parameters.Add to sqlcommand.Parameters.AddWithValue() the Server knows how to handle the Paramerterized values...

Comment: @DJKRAZE what is the added benefit in using AddWithValue over Add ?

Comment: Damo here is my best attempt at explaining this to you.. The difference is the implicit conversion when using AddWithValue. If you know that your executing SQL query (stored procedure) is accepting a value of type int, nvarchar, etc, there's no reason in re-declaring it in your code. but what if you don't know the Sever from my understanding should handle know the type based on the value of that @Parameter that you pass in.. Parameters.Add will also give you a nagging warning because it's been deprecated but still other OverLoads exist for the AddWithValues.. I hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so the basic syntax is as follows:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE NameOfProcedure
/*
I like to put modification history, purpose for the procedure and stuff like that in here.
It's not required though
*/
(
@afuser NVARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL
,@aftable INT DEFAULT NULL
```

Do this for all your variables, I've shown an example of an integer field and an nvarchar field but use whatever the datatype is. The DEFAULT NULL bit is the part that says if no value is specified, use NULL.

```
)
AS
BEGIN

INSERT INTO DataActions (afuser, aftable, changetype, originaldata, newdata)
VALUES (@afuser, @aftable, @changetype, @originaldata, @newdata)

END
```

Comment: When filling in the NameOfProcedure, use schema.name such as dbo.data_action_insert

Answer (score 2):

Well, you have to populate each parameter because it's in your SQL (unless you want to dynamically remove fields/values which would be messy).

I would just use the [NULL coalesce operator (??)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx) when setting the parameter values:

```
sqlcommand.Parameters.Add(
    new SqlParameter("afuser", userActions.AfUser ?? {insert default value here} ));
```

Comment: Assuming the default he wants is `NULL`, that would be `userActions.AfUser ?? DbNull.Value`

Answer (score 0):

you could do it using the DBNull value

`I would recommend using Parameters.AddWithValue() Method for example see the code below`

```
sqlcommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@afuser", userActions.AfUser ?? (object)DBNull.Value);
```

[MSDN SqlParameterCollection.AddWithValue Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparametercollection.addwithvalue.aspx)